# creating an address textfield like in apple's sms-app

Tags: iphone, sms, textfield, street-address

I'm writing an app, where I the user has to be able to select multiple adresses. I wanted to solve this in the same way, apple does when you send an SMS to someone.
You can enter text and it gets surrounded by a blue bubble for each adress selected.

I've already found facebook's tree20-kit, but I can't get it to work because of some linker error I cannot solve.

Is there any other kit out there, that's capable of doing this, or do you have any suggestions on how to create such a textField?

Yours,
   Bujtor

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  I don't know of any other open source solutions for this, and I think writing from scratch would be much more time consuming than trying to resolve the linker error.  I would recommend spending a few hours and do the following:

1. Create a new empty application.
2. Download Three20 and follow the detailed instructions on GitHub for linking the framework.

You should be able to get this to link as many others, including myself, have been able to use this framework.

Sorry this isn't a straight forward answer to your question.  I hope it was helpful just the same. Andrew.

Comment: well I have already spent about 2 days trying to make it work and it wouldn't hurt, if I couls show my boss some progress. So I'm working on the background logic first. I guess I'll try to extract the necessary things from three20 and recreate the feature based on that.
Thanks all the same.